# iphone registers for every OS update in Azure devices

Tags: azure

In Azure devices I am getting new Iphone device for each OS upgrade for all users. Is there any automated way to delete old ones?

Example:
I have

> IphoneName version 10.2.1
>
> SameIphoneName version 10.3.3

This also happens if user change the name of Iphone.

[Example image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGI6W.png)

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. What Azure devices are you referring to?

Comment: I am reffering to Azure Active Directore "devices". It still shows as preview, but probably peple get some info how to manage it =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is possible with Azure PowerShell:

you need to get all objects with:

```
   Get-MsolDevice -all | Where-object DisplayName -like "NAME" | select-object DisplayName, ApproximateLastLogonTimestamp, DeviceOsversion, ObjectID
```

And then Remove those ones which is old with

```
   Remove-MsolDevice -objectid ""
```